# Numba jit support for sorting with order

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Apparently Numba has difficulties to compile numpy.sort for record arrays when giving the sorting order. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

dt = np.dtype([("a", np.float_), ("b", np.float_)])

@njit
def sort_arr_jit(a: np.ndarray):
    a.sort(order=['a'])

pairs = np.array([(100, 1), (99, 2), (101, 3), (98, 4)], dtype=dt)

# Expecting to run in a jit compiled function
pairs1 = pairs.copy()
pairs1.sort(order=["a"])

# Bug
sort_arr_jit(pairs)
```

resulting in

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
- Resolution failure for literal arguments:
AssertionError()
- Resolution failure for non-literal arguments:
AssertionError()

During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction(array.sort for unaligned array(Record(a[type=float64;offset=0],b[type=float64;offset=8];16;False), 1d, C))
During: typing of call at /var/folders/z8/fdbqk6sj5pl25qx3l_8bj2d00000gn/T/ipykernel_34179/2264814377.py (8)
```

According to [this issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/461) np.sort should be supported but apparently not for record arrays.

How can I make it work? Thanks for any hint or suggestion.

Comment: The documentation clearly says it does not support the optional arguments of `sort`, https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/numpysupported.html#other-functions.  Can you use `argsort` on the desired field?

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for pointing it out to me. I had to write my own sorting that does the job.